# How to read text file into np.array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The text data is like the following:

```
a1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
b2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
c3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12
d4  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
e5  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14
f6  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15
g7  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
h8  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
i9  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
j10  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
```

How can I read this text file into np.array without the first column (the first column is the name of each row)? Many thanks.

PS. I tried np.loadtxt("filename") and got " could not convert string to float: b'a' " error

Comment: have you tried anything by yourself.? This really seems something where google can help you

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes, I searched and found several ways, but none of them works

Answer (score 5):

[`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) should work as long as you know the number of columns.

```
>>> a = np.loadtxt("file_name", usecols=range(1,11), dtype=np.float32)
>>> a
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.],
       [  2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.]])
```

Comment: @user133140, if you want the data as an int, you can specify that with `dtype=int`

Comment: I still get the error "could not convert string to float: b'OPEN'"

Comment: @user133140 then you have more in your text file then you showed us.

Comment: @user133140 that can only mean your file is different than what you wrote in the question

Comment: I am pretty sure the data is just like what I showed, the only difference is that my data looks like there are in an invisible excel table, could it be the reason?

Comment: @user133140: Please show the exact output of `print(repr(open("file_name").read(50)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

b = []
with open('data.txt') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for n in line.split()[1:]:
            b.append(int(n))
c = np.array(b)
```

Comment: Its a comment and a link only answer. Which is not really acceptable. Try to include the important code snippet in the question itself.

Comment: @ApritSolnaki Sorry, the answer was incorrect anyways.  I have updated the answer with a code snippet, but it looks like Siddharth already found a better solution.

Comment: I got error " invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'OPEN' "

Comment: @user133140 Are you stripping first element from from each line?

Comment: I just copyed your code and run, and I got that error.

Comment: @user133140 Have you created the input file data.txt?

Comment: This would be a good answer if the question was "How can I avoid using numpy to solve my numpy problem?"